# Tab4SE - the TAB key in your post

Tags: script, javascript, jquery

<kbd>Tab4SE</kbd>

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Tab4SE-Demo-SpectricSO]

### About

Uses SmartTabbing™ technology  to enable <kbd>Tab</kbd>ing (Indent) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing (Unindent).

Can be enabled via the toggle switch in the toolbar (preference is preserved). In accordance to [Stack Exchange Design Standards](https://stackoverflow.design/).

#### Download

| Version | Minified | Unminified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Version 1.2](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.2) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.2/script.min.user.js) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.2/script.user.js) |
| [Version 1.1](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.1) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.1/script.min.user.js) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.1/script.user.js) |
| [Version 1.0](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.0) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.0/script.min.user.js) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.0/script.user.js) |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

#### changelog

- ###### version 1.1

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to unindent
  - Add support for question textarea
  - Disabling/Enabling is now stored in LocalStorage, preserve preference
- ##### version 1.2

  - Firefox jQuery import issue patch for [report by Anonymous](https://stackapps.com/a/9026/76056)

---

##### For Developers

The unminified version provides an option to customize the number of spaces to indent on <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Simply go to [this line](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/95a5ae5442d793ecfba1b3883d561d13f0786ea0/scripts/Tab4SE/v1.1/script.user.js#L31) and follow the instructions in the comments.

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

After I have installed this userscript, I got the menu toolbar empty:

[image: Preview]

Also I have got this in the console:

```js
jQuery.Deferred exception: t.find(...).unadornedButtonClick is not a function c@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:9:7713
h@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:9:9001
et@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:9:19004
init@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:9:26949
StackExchange.question.fullInit@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:9:1900
init@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=9fbfb8dc3749:3:8327
inPageWatchSEFunction/obj[methodName]@https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462961/webmin-home-page-settings line 4360 > injectedScript:25:46
@https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462961/webmin-home-page-settings:54:40
i@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27449
fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213
Deferred/</e[f[0]]@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:29192
i/<@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=66447bb47e51:1:10595
y/<@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=66447bb47e51:1:16681
c@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:27742
fireWith@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:28487
Deferred/</s[t[0]]@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:30388
n/<@https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=66447bb47e51:1:15899
c@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:27742
fireWith@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:28487
e@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:29725
l/</t<@moz-extension://d4239b2b-2cbd-4319-a240-0b2e31c9f4b1/%20Tab4SE.user.js#28:2:29755
undefined
```

I am using Firefox 90.0.1. and using version 1.2 of this userscript.

**Update:**

I have uninstalled version 1.2 and installed earlier version which is version 1.1 and the problem is solved. Looks like the problem is from version 1.2.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Spectric 1.2 (Latest, thought).

Comment: @Spectric Weird. but I have uninstalled 1.2 and I installed 1.1 and it worked. So, I am not sure what is the problem. Looks like the problem is in 1.2 only.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Could we enable this userscript in the edit page?

When I try to edit anything (either question or answer), I don't see the option to turn on/off.

Here is an example:

[image: Preview]

I am not sure if this is a bug or feature-request but I will tag as feature request anyway.

Comment: I thought about this too. I'll consider implementing it in v1.3. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Fixed in version 1.2.

---

It doesn't work on Firefox with Windows 10, there is no option in the text box:

[image: textbox formatting controls without the Tab4SE option]

I tried version 1.0 also.  On closer inspection, I saw an error in the console:

```
Script error in [Greasemonkey script https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/Tab4SE; version 1.1]:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Tab4SE:76:19
```

Comment: @Spectric No, the script doesn't seem to be working at all.  I've encountered this error before on my scripts before, and this somehow happened suddenly where the script was working before.  It might my browser's privacy settings blocking jQuery from loading.

Comment: @Spectric Doesn't work, I even disabled all the privacy protections on my browser.  Maybe it has something to do with the way your script loads jQuery?  This is very strange.

Comment: I've updated the file to explicitly import jQuery. It should work now.